# Why SPListItem.Update doesn't trigger workflows?

Tags: workflow, splistitem, updatelistitems

I have a workflow with Start Option "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" and I have code that execute SPListItem.Update(), but this update doesn't force workflow to run execution. Why it doesn't work and how can I workaround this issue?

UPDATE: The workflow was created by SharePoint Designer and I don't use any Workflow functionality in my code, I just change values of SPListItems and update them.

Comment: Let us see your code, as well as what context (event receiver? etc).

Comment: What user account are you running as?  Try running as a non-Administrator account and see if your workflows fire.

Comment: is your timer service running?

Comment: does your workflow run if you manually update the list item?

Comment: @David Lozzi Yes, service is running, it was the first thing that I checked with this issue.

Comment: @justforkix09 Yes, if I do manual update it works like a charm! I made workaround for this issue (now workflow simply starts by shedule), but i still wonder why it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

please pay attention to the Task List. The Task lists execute the Workflow really. If you don't finalize the assigned task, your WF not run. This is my code to exceute a task and make te WF continue by the steps:

This code it's used ina SP WebPart, with a WorkFlow with two approvers.:

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    try
                    {
                        SPList task = web.Lists["Tasks"];
                        SPListItem item = task.Items.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["ID"]));
                        if (item["WorkflowListId"] != null)
                        {
                            Guid sourceListID = new Guid(item["WorkflowListId"].ToString());
                            SPList sourceList = web.Lists.GetList(sourceListID, true);
                            int sourceListItemID = Convert.ToInt32(item["WorkflowItemId"]);
                            SPListItem sourceListItem = sourceList.GetItemById(sourceListItemID);

                         if (sourceListItem["Aprobador"].ToString() == "Aprobador 1" && Convert.ToString(sourceListItem["State"]) == "En Revisión")
                            {

                           sourceListItem["State"] = "Approved 1";
                                sourceListItem["Approver"] = "Approver 1";
                                sourceListItem.Update();

                                //Get the workflow instance id from Task item
                                Guid taskWorkflowInstanceID = new Guid(item["WorkflowInstanceID"].ToString());
                                SPWorkflow workflow = item.Workflows[taskWorkflowInstanceID];
                                SPWorkflowTask wfTask = workflow.Tasks[item.UniqueId];
                                Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
                                ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.Completed] = "TRUE";
                                ht["Completed"] = "TRUE";
                                ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.PercentComplete] = 1.0f;
                                ht["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
                                ht["Status"] = "Completed";
                                ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.TaskStatus] = SPResource.GetString(new CultureInfo((int)wfTask.Web.Language, false), Strings.WorkflowStatusInProgress, new object[0]);
                                ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowOutcome] = "Approved";
                                ht["TaskStatus"] = "Approved";
                                ht["FormData"] = SPWorkflowStatus.InProgress;


                                SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask((wfTask as SPListItem), ht, true);
                                Response.Redirect(Request.Params["Source"]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (sourceListItem["Approver"].ToString() == "Aprobador 1" && Convert.ToString(sourceListItem["State"]) == "Approved 1")
                                {
                                    sourceListItem["State"] = "Approved 2";
                                    sourceListItem["Aprobador"] = "Approver 2";
                                    sourceListItem.Update();

                                    //Get the workflow instance id from Task item
                                    Guid taskWorkflowInstanceID = new Guid(item["WorkflowInstanceID"].ToString());
                                    SPWorkflow workflow = item.Workflows[taskWorkflowInstanceID];
                                    SPWorkflowTask wfTask = workflow.Tasks[item.UniqueId];
                                    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
                                    ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.Completed] = "TRUE";
                                    ht["Completed"] = "TRUE";
                                    ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.PercentComplete] = 1.0f;
                                    ht["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
                                    ht["Status"] = "Completed";
                                    ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.TaskStatus] = SPResource.GetString(new CultureInfo((int)wfTask.Web.Language, false), Strings.WorkflowStatusInProgress, new object[0]);
                                    ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowOutcome] = "Approved";
                                    ht["TaskStatus"] = "Approved";
                                    ht["FormData"] = SPWorkflowStatus.InProgress;

                                    SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask((wfTask as SPListItem), ht, true);
                                    Response.Redirect(Request.Params["Source"]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The list with attached WF have a two fields: Approver and State. But the code that run the Task and make advance the WF it's:

```
 SPList task = web.Lists["Tasks"];
 SPListItem item = task.Items.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["ID"]));

 Guid taskWorkflowInstanceID = new Guid(item["WorkflowInstanceID"].ToString());
 SPWorkflow workflow = item.Workflows[taskWorkflowInstanceID];
 SPWorkflowTask wfTask = workflow.Tasks[item.UniqueId];
 Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
 ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.Completed] = "TRUE";
 ht["Completed"] = "TRUE";
 ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.PercentComplete] = 1.0f;
 ht["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
 ht["Status"] = "Completed";
 ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.TaskStatus] = SPResource.GetString(new CultureInfo((int)wfTask.Web.Language, false), Strings.WorkflowStatusInProgress, new object[0]);
  ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowOutcome] = "Approved";
  ht["TaskStatus"] = "Approved";
  ht["FormData"] = SPWorkflowStatus.InProgress;

  SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask((wfTask as SPListItem), ht, true);
```

Comment: You see, i don't use any Workflow functionality in my code. The workflow was created with SharePoint Designer and for some reason it isn't start when my code execute update.

Comment: Hi exactly, my code it's for a SP Designer WF, not WorkFlow Foundation, see you!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you associate that workflow with a list yet? see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/03/31/associate-an-spd-workflow-with-a-specific-task-list.aspx)
 and [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298934%28office.12%29.aspx) link to associate your workflow with list/library.

And if you have associate your workflow 
with list/library but still not running, try to change your workflow behavior ie add log to history activity or send email activity to *debug* your workflow on runtime.

Also its a good idea to post some of your code (where do you write that *splistitem.update* thing) and explain more clearly to forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating List item using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()` statement, you have to use below SPSite constructor for creating object of SPSite.
`using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteURL, UserToken))`

For, fetching `UserToken` you may use below statement:

```
var userToken = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers["domain\\user"].UserToken;
```